# save multiple values for same key hash Map in a loop java

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I need to add a separate values to a Same key in HashMap in java not in just once. But in a Loop or when ever I need enter those values.for example if key is 1 then values for that is may be 3,5,7,8

```
    count=0;
    while (true) {

        Packet info = captor.getPacket();

    if (info != null)   

        if(info instanceof TCPPacket){       /////         TCP

            TCPPacket tc= (TCPPacket) info;

         }

        if(info instanceof UDPPacket){    ////              UDP

            UDPPacket ud= (UDPPacket) info;

        }
```

I am saving the packet number for each packet. and i need to save the number of packets for each Ip address getting IP address as key

Comment: Make the value a collection type?

Comment: This is not nearly enough information for us to be able to help you. Describe the problem in more detail, and tell us what you have tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Okey, so that is kind of a problem statement (though not a very crisp one). Any code with that? Pseudo code? Some attempts of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways:

(assuming your keys are of type String and your values are of type Object)

1. Instead of `HashMap<String, Object>` use `HashMap<String, Collection<Object>>`
2. Use `MultiMap<String, Object>` from commons collections or guava. (Link: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html )